# Android crash when Back Button pressed

Tags: android, listview, button, crash

In Activity(A) I lunch Activity(B) with `startActivityForResult(intent, 2)`, but when I press the back button in the Activity (B), the app crash.
Code in Activity(B)

```
.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Deg f = dettagli.get(position);

                 Intent intent=new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra("value1", f.value1);
                 intent.putExtra("value2", f.value2);
                 setResult(2,intent);

                    finish();

            }
        });
        return row;
```

This is 
LogCat`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo
{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {Activity_o}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Can You provde full stacktrace? Are You sure that `f` is not null?

Comment: Yes, it's null. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the object f is null, your other code is all right!

```
if(f)
{

Intent intent=new Intent();

intent.putExtra("value1", f.value1);

intent.putExtra("value2", f.value2);

setResult(2,intent);

finish();
}
```